# Update Trigger Distinct Date

Tags: mysql, date, triggers, insert

I'm doing a project and I got stuck on this trigger. This is the two tables involved.

```
    ---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_tra        | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| nombre_tra    | varchar(100)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| apellidos_tra | varchar(100)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dni_tra       | varchar(1000) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| telefono_tra  | int(10)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| falta_tra     | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dias_tra      | int(255)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_rec       | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_tra_rec   | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| id_var_rec   | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| fecha_rec    | date     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| cantidad_rec | int(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

On this case, ***id_tra*** and ***id_tra_rec*** are related, and I need a trigger to update the ***dias_tra*** on ***dias_tra*** + 1 for **id_tra = id_tra_rec** when there is an *INSERT* on the second table image. 
Thats relatively easy but the strange thing is that the Insert could have different data but the same date (**fecha_rec**), so the trigger must know if there is a row with the same id and the same date(**fecha_rec**) to not to update the **dias_tra**. Something like a select distinct. Here is what i tried:

```
create trigger dias_tra 
after insert on datos_recogida
for each row
begin
if (select fecha_rec from datos_recogida where id_tra_rec=new.id_trarec and fecha_rec=new.fecha_rec)
update datos_trabajadores set dias_tra = dias_tra +1 where id_tra=new.id_tra_rec
end if;
end;
```

Sorry for my English, first time here, hope you understanding. If you need more information I'm around here :)

Comment: Try an if not exists test. AND every if needs a THEN and You con't seem to be setting delimiters,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say when datos_trabajadores is created so here's a trigger which checks and creates if necessary. I have used a simple count to check if check if id_tra_rec and fecha_rec already exist - this is an after insert trigger so a count of 1 means its the first one. note the debug_table is there to debug you should remove when you are happy.

```
drop table if exists datos_recogida,datos_trabajadores;
create table datos_trabajadores
( id_tra         int(11)  auto_increment primary key,
 nombre_tra     varchar(100)  ,
 apellidos_tra  varchar(100)  ,
 dni_tra        varchar(1000) ,
 telefono_tra   int(10)       ,
 falta_tra      date          ,
 dias_tra       int(255)      )
;
create table datos_recogida
( id_rec        int(11)   auto_increment primary key,
 id_tra_rec    int(11)  ,
 id_var_rec    int(11)  ,
 fecha_rec     date     ,
 cantidad_rec  int(255) );

drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$

create trigger t after insert on datos_recogida
for each row
begin
    if (select count(*) from datos_recogida where id_tra_rec = new.id_tra_rec and fecha_rec = new.fecha_rec) = 1 then
        insert into debug_table(msg) values (concat('not found:',new.id_tra_rec,':',new.fecha_rec));
        if not exists(select 1 from datos_trabajadores where dias_tra = new.id_tra_rec) then
            insert into debug_table(msg) values ('inserting');
            insert into datos_trabajadores(dias_tra,nombre_tra) values (new.id_tra_rec,1);
        else
            insert into debug_table(msg) values ('Updating');
            update datos_trabajadores
                set nombre_tra = nombre_tra + 1
                where dias_tra = new.id_tra_rec;
        end if;
    end if;

end $$
delimiter ;

truncate table debug_table;
truncate table datos_recogida;
truncate table datos_trabajadores;

insert into datos_recogida (id_tra_rec,fecha_rec) 
values
(1,'2019-01-01'),
(1,'2019-01-01'),
(1,'2019-01-02');

select * from debug_table;
select * from datos_trabajadores;

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from debug_table;
+----+------------------------+------+
| id | msg                    | MSG2 |
+----+------------------------+------+
|  1 | not found:1:2019-01-01 | NULL |
|  2 | inserting              | NULL |
|  3 | not found:1:2019-01-02 | NULL |
|  4 | Updating               | NULL |
+----+------------------------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from datos_trabajadores;
+--------+------------+---------------+---------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| id_tra | nombre_tra | apellidos_tra | dni_tra | telefono_tra | falta_tra | dias_tra |
+--------+------------+---------------+---------+--------------+-----------+----------+
|      1 | 2          | NULL          | NULL    |         NULL | NULL      |        1 |
+--------+------------+---------------+---------+--------------+-----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Great, i didn't realize that way. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` to check if there is a record with the same data.

```
BEGIN

     IF(EXISTS(select fecha_rec from datos_recogida where id_tra_rec=new.id_trarec and fecha_rec=new.fecha_rec)) THEN

          //If the record exists do what you need.

     ELSE 

          update datos_trabajadores set dias_tra = dias_tra +1 where id_tra=new.id_tra_rec

     END IF;
END;
```

Comment: END IF not ENDIF

Comment: it didn ' t work for me :( but thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution of P.Salmon helped me to get a simplified way to do it. Thanks every body and hope helps somebody.

```
drop trigger if exists dias_tra;
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER dias_tra AFTER INSERT ON datos_recogida FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE dias INT;
SET dias = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT fecha_rec) AS diasmes FROM datos_recogida WHERE id_tra_rec=NEW.id_tra_rec);
UPDATE datos_trabajadores SET dias_tra = dias where id_tra=NEW.id_tra_rec;
END; $$
```